# Footer div closing early on a single web page

Tags: php

I am working on a website, http://www.amp.com.pk/contact/. The footer works perfect on all of the pages except the contact page. I have tried wrapping the footer under another div (primary div) but still the problem is there.

Please guide me. Thanks.

```
<div class="footer-wrapper">

                <div class="copyright"> 
                <p style="margin-top:-45px;color:#91703A;font-size:15px;">Adnan Malik Productions</p>
<p style="margin-top:-30px;color:#91703A;font-size:13px;">
Follow us on <a href="http://www.facebook.com/adnanmalikproductions" target="_blank">Facebook</a> | <a href="http://www.twitter.com/adnanmalik " target="_blank">Twitter</a>|AMP &copy; <?php echo date('Y') ?>.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</div></p>

                <div class="credit">Powered By: <a href="http://www.inspurate.com/" target="_blank">Inspurate</a></div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>
```

Comment: not the issue, but you have `<div class="copyright"><p style="margin-top:-45px;color:#91703A;font-size:15px;">...</div></p>` where you close your `<div>` inside your `<p>`

Comment: I changed it but the footer still does not work.

Comment: thats why I said 'not the issue'. Also, you have an unclosed `<span>` -> `<h1 onClick="location.href='http://www.amp.com.pk/'" id="site-title"><span>ADNAN MALIK PRODUCTIONS</h1>`.

Comment: Please make your HTML [valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amp.com.pk%2Fcontact%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score -1):

```
#colophon .footer-wrapper
{
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

try this and see if it works or not or try giving dimensions in Percent instead of Pixels !
I am sure it will work

Comment: may i know the reason of -1?

Comment: Because this is not the answer. OP's html was closed incorrectly